# get linkedin profile

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am now building new application in which I need to fetch the [linkedin](http://www.linkedin.com/) profile information of users after successful authentication. I have created the following steps as per the document:

```
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api
```

I have put below code in head section -

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
          api_key: meufo7vcx8ul
          authorize: true
        </script>
```

and this into body section, But I'm confused at this part of code:

```
<script type="in/Login">
    Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
```

when I am trying to run this page, it gives the `syntax error`.
I don't understand where do I get the profile information array.

Comment: What is returning the syntax error? PHP? Your browser? What is the exact error message?

Comment: the error is on line                                              Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.   
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in ../linkedIn.php

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. Is it a PHP error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error you mentioned, **Turn off PHP short open tags.**. And for getting profile information: See this link: [Linkedin Profile Info](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_profile/) sample code.

Or try:

```
<script type="in/Login">
Hello, <?php echo '<' . '?js= firstname ?' . '>' ; ?> <?php echo '<' . '?js= lastName ?' . '>' ; ?>.
</script>
```